# Make a copy of Database by converting its units

Tags: c#, sqlite

My application needs a database in two units (`SI`, `US`).. Once the user chooses to work with `SI` units, on exit I need to convert the values to `US` and save it in the US DB

Suppose the user picks(SI units) and does some editings to the variable THickness on one of the forms.

On exit, I should save these in the SI units DB also. Currently the program does all the save inputs.... and other stuff only in one DB.

Any inputs on how to accomplish this will be good

Here's what I've done so far
On Exit, create another connection for a schema creation,

```
private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DbConnection c = CreateConnectionForSchemaCreation("STAR-SI.Sqlite");
    this.Close();   
}

public DbConnection CreateConnectionForSchemaCreation(string fileName)
{
    var connOther = new SQLiteConnection();
    connOther.ConnectionString = new DbConnectionStringBuilder()
    {
        {"Data Source", fileName},
        {"Version", "3"},
        {"FailIfMissing", "False"},
    }.ConnectionString;

    connOther.Open();
    return connOther;
}
```

Comment: You could always store the values in one unit. Then when you retrieve the values, optionally convert to another unit based on the user's preferences.

Answer (score 2):

What if the user converts back and forth multiple times?  It seems like having to regenerate the database every time the user switches units is unnecessarily complex.

Is there a definitive 1:1 mapping between each possible choice for SI units to a corresponding choice in US measurements?

I would suggest one of the following:

- If there is a 1:1 mapping, store in one of SI or US units and convert if needed to the other in the application layer
- If there is no 1:1 mapping, have nullable columns for SI and US units in a single database.  Store the user's selection in the appropriate column and null the other column.

Comment: The user cannot switch between Databases. He has the exit the application to do so.

Comment: It's still too complex to re-create the entire database just to switch units.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong way to do this you should have a UnitOfMeasure field stored with the value.

e.g.

```
"Weight 1",1,"kilogram"
"Weight 2",2.2,"lb"
```

Then on the user's profile, they have a preference for SI or US and you convert as required for the operations on the data.

A couple of database functions, an extra column, a table to hold UOM, and one for conversions, job done.

Not to mention you can then deal with in system conversions like 16 ounces to the pound etc, which almost exactly the same code.